# How to access subclass variables through a reference of the superclass with C#

Tags: c#

I have a **User** class which is my parent class. and I have a **SiteAdmin** class which is inherited from **User** class:

```
public abstract class User { }
public class SiteAdmin : User 
{
   public string ProfilePicUrl { get; set; }
}
```

The scenario is I want to check if an **User** instance is a type of **SiteAdmin** class, then access to **SiteAdmin** properties with **User** object. Suppose **ProfilePicUrl** is a property of **SiteAdmin** class. How can I access this propery with **User** object?

```
if (comment.User is SiteAdmin)
{
   var profilePicUrl = comment.User.ProfilePicUrl;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you promote the ProfilePicUrl as virtual to the User class?

Comment: Please don't do: `
if (comment.User is SiteAdmin)
{
   var profilePicUrl = (comment.User as SiteAdmin).ProfilePicUrl;
}
`

Comment: @Oliver - Why do you say that? This seems like a very normal scenario.

Comment: @OguzOzgul - Why not?

Comment: @Enigmativity Because that does a second unneeded cast.  Either `if (comment.User is SiteAdmin siteAdmin)` or `var siteAdmin = comment.User as SiteAdmin; if(siteAdmin != null)` will achieve the result with just one cast.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not that. As @oliver also commented out in a different but correct phrasing, this implementation is braking two out of five SOLID design principles. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID 1. Open/Close Principle. What are you going to do when a new super class is introduced and the same kind of need is arised? Change the super class. Oh. The impact of doing this is to test every functionality employing the super class and all its subclasses. 2. Liskov Substitution Principle. Please read "Design by contract" also. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract

Comment: @OguzOzgul - I'm not with you on this. What the OP has appears to be a quite normal pattern. The only confusing thing here is that they have used the property named `ProfilePicUrl` which we imagine could also apply to the super-class. If the property were `SiteAdminId` then we would know that it doesn't belong to the super-class. I think this question should be taken at face value that the class definition is correct.

Comment: @Enigmativity I think we need to clarify one thing here. Because you and I probably do not have the same understanding of the question. Dear OP. Where do you execute this code? Inside the super class (as your question TITLE tells us) or somewhere else, somewhere where you have to work with the abstraction User, like inside the controller of the dashboard for example? Can you please clarify?

Comment: @OguzOzgul I think misinterpreted this in the same way. On re-reading, the question seems to simply relate to performing conditional logic based on type - which is absolutely normal!

Comment: @OguzOzgul - I understand that this code is being run in a separate class entirely. It's not being run in the super-class.

Comment: @Enigmativity it seems so to me too now. Because if it was in the super-class the OP would access the instance by `this` I think. But the title still says otherwise :) (Which I am going to edit)

Comment: @OguzOzgul In the controller, I have filled the **User** property of **comment** with an object of **SiteAdmin** class. that's because casting works. btw My question title was confusing. thanks for editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (comment.User is SiteAdmin siteAdmin)
{
    var profilePicUrl = siteAdmin.ProfilePicUrl;
}
```

Or you could do this:

```
if (comment.User is SiteAdmin)
{
    var profilePicUrl = (comment.User as SiteAdmin).ProfilePicUrl;
}
```

Comment: Personally I wouldn't create a circular dependency between base-class and sub-class.  That's why I think it defeats the object of a base class.

Comment: @Oliver - Can you explain what you mean by a "circular dependency" in this circumstance? Are you saying it is part of my code or the OP's?

Comment: My mistake, I misread the question as type checking the sub-class from *within* the base-class!

Answer (score 0):

You could define contract between super and subclass, e.g. an abstract method, on `User` and `SiteAdmin` implements the abstract method and returns `ProfilePicUrl`.